# mobile select menu stay on current URL select option

Tags: jquery, html, forms, mobile

jQuery:

```
   $(function() {
            $('select').change(function(){
            var url = $(this).val();
            window.location = url;
            });
       });
```

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="http://www.coolwebsite.com.au/Sandbox/">Home</option>
  <option value="http://www.coolwebsite.com.au/Sandbox/kitchen.php">Kitchens</option>
  <option value="http://www.coolwebsite.com.au/Sandbox/fitouts.php">Shop Fitouts</option>
  <option value="http://www.coolwebsite.com.au/Sandbox/officefitouts.php">Office Fitouts</option>
  <option value="http://www.coolwebsite.com.au/Sandbox/Gallery/">Gallery</option>
  <option value="http://www.coolwebsite.com.au/Sandbox/joinery.php">Joinery</option>
  <option value="http://www.coolwebsite.com.au/Sandbox/jobs.php">Recent Jobs</option>
  <option value="http://www.coolwebsite.com.au/Sandbox/contact.php">Contact Us</option>
</select>
```

It works just fine, but once the select option is clicked and new page appears, the `select` box returns to 'Home' option, rather than current page.

Wondering how to keep this option selected.

Comment: Have I understood this right? You want to reload the page and the selected value on the new page should be set to what you selected from the previous?

Comment: You will need to add the selected page as the selected value in the relevant php page.  E.g. if you select `Kitchens` from home you will need to set the select in `kitchen.php` to read `<option selected value="http://www.coolwebsite.com.au/Sandbox/kitchen.php">Kitchens</option>`

Comment: I am loading my mobile menu from a php include, the same php include throughout all pages so this solution wouldn't be optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function()
    var url = window.location.href;
    $('select option[value="'+url+'"]').prop("selected",true);
});
```

Comment: He's reloading the page. This will not work upon reload

Answer (score 0):

Since you're reloading the page, it's the code generating the page (in this case the PHP code) that must write the attribute `selected` to the corresponding `<option>` tag.

```
<select>
  <option value="http://www.coolwebsite.com.au/Sandbox/">Home</option>
  <option value="http://www.coolwebsite.com.au/Sandbox/kitchen.php" selected>Kitchens</option>
  ...
</select>
```